# Grep: Delete the first word of everyline

Tags: grep

I have a long document and need to delete the first word in every line.

Is this possible with Grep? I've searched online, but can only find tutorials for deleting first words of a certain type (e.g. all words that start with `?`). I need to delete the first word regardless of its contents.

For example:

```
THE TOURIST OFFICE
Isabel Good morning! My name’s Isabel.
Colleague Where do you live in Salamanca?
Juan Condal Hotel.
OUTSIDE THE CONDAL HOTEL
```

Becomes

```
TOURIST OFFICE
Good morning! My name’s Isabel.
Where do you live in Salamanca?
Condal Hotel.
THE CONDAL HOTEL
```

It would be even better if it could skip words that are in all capitals.

For example

```
THE TOURIST OFFICE
Isabel Good morning! My name’s Isabel.
Colleague Where do you live in Salamanca?
Juan Condal Hotel.
OUTSIDE THE CONDAL HOTEL
```

becomes

```
THE TOURIST OFFICE
Good morning! My name’s Isabel.
Where do you live in Salamanca?
Condal Hotel.
OUTSIDE THE CONDAL HOTEL
```

Comment: Could you match on the `\s` or `:space:` character?, find the first in the line and capture the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/^[A-Z]*[a-z]+ (.*)/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
THE TOURIST OFFICE
Good morning! My name’s Isabel.
Where do you live in Salamanca?
Condal Hotel.
OUTSIDE THE CONDAL HOTEL
```

Comment: Worth noting this won't handle the case where a line starts without a capital letter.

Comment: This works perfectly. NB for anyone trying this, you have to use a linux system - it doesn't work under MacOSX.

Comment: @big_smile: This will probably work with BSD grep: `sed 's/^[A-Z]*[a-z][a-z]* \(.*\)/\1/' file`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first case, deleting first word regardless of case, you can use the following sed command:

```
sed "s/^\S*\s//g" file
```

Comment: To remove a word with at least one lower case letter: `sed -r 's/^\S*[[:lower:]]\S*\s+//' file`